# SQL One to many relations issue when pulling data

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an issue with a query:
[image]

For any given `IntakeQCID` I have a lot of `IntakeQCDetailID`'s and a lot of Questions and Answers. Now I need to select each question and answer to be on a separate column.

Something like this works:

```
SSELECT     IntakeQC.IntakeQCID, IntakeQC.PalletID, Max(CASE WHEN QCProductQuestions.QCQuestionID = 106 THEN CAST(Answer AS varchar(10)) ELSE '' END) AS ArrivalTemperature
FROM         QCProductQuestions INNER JOIN
                      IntakeQCDetails ON QCProductQuestions.QCProductQuestionID = IntakeQCDetails.QCProductQuestionID INNER JOIN
                      IntakeQC ON IntakeQCDetails.IntakeQCID = IntakeQC.IntakeQCID INNER JOIN
                      QCQuestions ON QCProductQuestions.QCQuestionID = QCQuestions.QCQuestionID
WHERE     (QCProductQuestions.Intake = 1) AND (IntakeQC.IntakeQCID = 9413) AND (IntakeQCDetails.Answer <> '')
Group By IntakeQC.IntakeQCID, IntakeQC.PalletID
```

Here's the output:

[image]

If I don't do this if a particular `IntakeQCID` has 20 QC Questions I get 20 rows of data and I only want one..

However the problem is that I've got 170+ `QCQuestions` in my scope and I have to do it for every single one. Is there more elegant way of achieving this?

Any Help, Ideas or Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `PIVOT` is the answer, but you'll probably need to dynamically define the columns for it. In the long run you'll find it's easier to have SQL just return the data in tabular form (fixed columns, many rows) as above and then use a spreadsheet or reporting tool to manage the formatting and presentation of the data. For instance, this would just be a simple Pivot Table in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could do the trick for you http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/ 
Maybe you could provide a DDL for the tables, this way it should be easier for us to test your code and other things

Comment: Maybe you could add an explanation of what the solution would be along with the link.

Comment: Unfortunately my goal is to create a separate column for each answer, not concatenate all the results in to one column as your answer suggests. I do believe that `PIVOT` is the best solution in this case.